# Free Replacements for Aviary API / Creative Cloud SDK Image Editor?

Tags: adobe, image-manipulation, aviary, adobecreativesdk, image-editor

Looks like Adobe is killing the Image Editor part of their CC SDK, aka the Aviary API. Does anyone know of a similar free image editor API with a nice and simple UI?